# How to handle the viewControllers when building a view like instagram's profile view?

Tags: ios, layout, uiscrollview

[image: prototype of the profile view design]

Yep.Just like the photo showing,it's a mockup style of a profile view like instagram's.When users pressed Grid button,the view will show images by grid style.When users pressed List button,the view will show images in a list and the grid view is hide.Any buttons users pressed ,the user profile view will be never changed.

I have several plans to handle this situation but I think that my plans are not optimized.So I'm eager to hear better ideas.

I can share my plans here :

Plan A :

```
UIViewController
  -> UITableView
    -> UIView ( as the user profile UIView )
    -> UITableViewCell1 ( could be the first section's cell and include all images with grid style )
    -> UITableViewCell2 ( when the style changed to list , reuse another UITableViewCell for handling )
```

When users pressed Grid button,just show Cell1.Otherwise it would show Cell2.

I think that this plan is odd because of the structure of the views.Especially UITableViewCell1.

Plan B :

```
UIScrollViewContrller
  -> UITableView ( for handling images in list style )
  -> UICollectionView ( for handling images in grid style )
```

In this solution,I may face another problem : handling scrollView inside a scrollView.Maybe I should add a pan gesture to check the vertical scrolling and users can feel the scrolling is perfect.

When users pressed grid button it would show UITableView.Otherwise show UICollectionView.

Really hope to hear your advices for me.

Comment: Finally I do practice by Plan B.And I use a UIScrollView as a container and several UIViews inside it.Here is the project : https://github.com/lbj96347/ProfileView .

Answer (score 0):

Plan A looks too complex IMO, especially that high level view table view. You can do a lot with table views but they also have drawbacks and getting precise control over them can end up being time consuming. I would even thing about not using them at all, personally I never use them for anything anymore other than things that actually look like lists.

Anyway to make things more manageable you could consider adding a container view in the bottom half, within that container view you would load a separate view controller for each different display.
That way you are also partitioning up your code a lot - i.e. you would have one view controller whose responsibility is just to display your grid, another view controller to just display the list style etc. etc.

Comment: Yes.Your advice is similar to Plan B.BTW,it seems that many people are unwilling to use UITableView anymore.It's like a trend. :-)